# Add current date to Excel Macro

Tags: excel, vba

can someone help me edit this Excel macro? On the right footer, I want the current date to display in mm/dd/yy format.

```
Sub Document_Standards()
'
' Document_Standards Macro
'

'
    ActiveWindow.View = xlPageLayoutView
    Selection.Font.Size = 12
    Selection.Font.Size = 14
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .LeftHeader = ""
        .CenterHeader = "&""-,Bold""&14&F"
        .RightHeader = ""
        .LeftFooter = "Created by Chris"
        .CenterFooter = "CONFIDENTIAL"
        .RightFooter = "Printed on Date ()"
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.7)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.7)
        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .Zoom = 100
        .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
        .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
        .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
        .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
        .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True
        .EvenPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
    End With
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 1")).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried something other than `""` for a value to `RightFooter.Text`?

Comment: `"Printed on Date ()"` should be `"Printed on " & Date()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
Sub Document_Standards()
'
' Document_Standards Macro
'

'
    ActiveWindow.View = xlPageLayoutView
    Selection.Font.Size = 12
    Selection.Font.Size = 14
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    Application.PrintCommunication = False
    With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
        .LeftHeader = ""
        .CenterHeader = "&""-,Bold""&14&F"
        .RightHeader = ""
        .LeftFooter = "Created by Chris"
        .CenterFooter = "CONFIDENTIAL"
        .RightFooter = "Printed on " & Date()
        .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.7)
        .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.7)
        .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.75)
        .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.3)
        .Zoom = 100
        .PrintErrors = xlPrintErrorsDisplayed
        .OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = False
        .DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = False
        .ScaleWithDocHeaderFooter = True
        .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter = True
        .EvenPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
        .EvenPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.LeftHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.CenterHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.RightHeader.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.LeftFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.CenterFooter.Text = ""
        .FirstPage.RightFooter.Text = ""
    End With
    Application.PrintCommunication = True
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 1")).Select
End Sub
```